# What does "Depth Control = No" on a table saw mean?

Tags: table-saw, power-tools

I'm looking to buy the Skilsaw SPT99-12 table saw but I noticed on the sale listing it says "Depth Control = No".

Does this mean I can't adjust the blade up and down?

Will the blade stay in place during a cut if it is adjustable?

Comment: More context about where you read "Depth Control = No" is needed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about web site wording, and isn't generally useful for woodworking in general, nor will it be useful as that web site is updated. This is something to contact the retailer about.

Answer (score 4):

I went to the skill saw [website page for that saw](https://www.skilsaw.com/wormdrive-table-saw-spt99-12/)

I can not find the phrase  "Depth Control = No" in the specs.

It displays a photo that clearly show the blade adjustment crank handle.

> Will the blade stay in place during a cut if it is adjustable?

Yes, once you set the blade height it will not change or move up and down while you make your cut. It will only move up or down if and when you turn the adjustment crank.

I am not sure why the page you were looking at had that "no" reference for depth of cut but this is a normal table saw with an adjustable depth of cut feature. **Perhaps it means no depth of cut gauge or indicator ?**

It is nice portable saw. Send one to me.

Comment: I should have added that it is on Lowes where it indicates "Depth Control" of "No". Thank you for the response. I'm new to all of this but thought it would be a good starter table saw.

Comment: Do you need a portable saw ? If you do not you  may find a dedicated shop saw with larger table to be more user friendly. I only  found the SPT99-11 on there web site,  it says "depth control X  not "NO"  Maybe X means not applicable.

Comment: I've found that both Lowes and Home Depot tend to add rows to those tables that don't apply to every item, especially when you use the compare feature. Often it is because one item is promoting some special feature (or has a fancy name for  a standard feature) that forces them to enter a value for every other item in the category.

Comment: "X" means any one of "not applicable, unknown, no". These tables are created (or corrected) by humans with little domain knowledge and incomplete data in front of them.

Comment: +1 for going to the manufacturer page instead of a sales company page to look at specs.